# Println needs a message, help decrypt log cat

Tags: android, clipboard, logcat

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message 
at android.util.Log.println_native(Native Method) 
at android.util.Log.e(Log.java:230) 
at android.sec.clipboard.data.ClipboardDataMgr.addData(ClipboardDataMgr.java:166) 
at com.android.server.sec.InternalClipboardExService.addData(InternalClipboardExService.java:438) 
at com.android.server.sec.InternalClipboardExService.access$300(InternalClipboardExService.java:75) 
at com.android.server.sec.InternalClipboardExService$1.run(InternalClipboardExService.java:389) 
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
```

Seem to be getting this quite often in my crash reporting, i can't for the life of my understand how or why or even where its happening?

The only location im performing anything on the clipboard is to copy data to it, no logging or println of any kind, not to mention i'm choosing the correct methods for the version of OS at runtime so i didnt hit any compat issues.

oh, and the devices range from 2.2 right up to 4.0 OS version

Perhaps relevant code?

```
int currentapiVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
if (currentapiVersion >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
    try {
        android.content.ClipboardManager clipboard = (android.content.ClipboardManager) acc
                .getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
        ClipData clip = ClipData.newPlainText("", b);
        clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
} else {
    try {
        android.text.ClipboardManager clipboard = (android.text.ClipboardManager) acc
                .getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
        clipboard.setText(b);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually, you are logging TWICE: `e.printStackTrace();`

Comment: Only one is called depending on the OS version, and then only if it is caught

Comment: I am just saying that you are logging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anyway, your error is not there: It is not catched by your `try...catch` because it is happening on another thread as you can see in your stack trace.

According to the developers of [Clipper - Clipboard Manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.rojekti.clipper):

`SAMSUNG USERS: Some devices have a randomly occurring bug that may cause the clipboard to crash in any application. This is unfortunately out of our control. If you are experiencing this problem with your device, please contact Samsung support for assistance.`

This might be also caused (later on since you said up to 4.0) by version 4.3:
[Copy crash in Android 4.3 when clipboard listener attached](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=58043)

Also read this guy's post (seems he experienced the issue): http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2097929

---

In summary, I do not think this error is your responsibility.

Comment: Thanks to the both of you Sherif and http://stackoverflow.com/users/501696/blackbelt glad i can finally get an answer to this, perhaps it will help others in future. For now, i'll leave it. Beyond my control.

Answer (score 2):

the error means that the second parameter of `Log.*` can not be null, otherwise a N`enter code here`PE is thrown. That could happen, for instance, when you try to print the message returned by an exception (`e.getMessage())`.

```
String message = null;
Log.i("TAG", message);
```

that`s kind of situation are the cause of that exception. A possible workaround

```
String message = null;
Log.i("TAG", ((message == null) ? "string null" : message));
```

Comment: I thought as much, but im NOT doing that anywhere, no logs, nothing

Comment: I see, that`s what the exception mean. Without seeing the entire stacktrace or relevant snippet of code it is impossible to understand what`s going on

Comment: added the code, is it perhaps the e.printStackTraces? It's never happened ever, nor anywhere else?

Comment: what is the variable b? Is a String? is it != null?

Comment: String selectedValue = nameValue;
            String a = selectedValue.replace("/", "");
            String b = a.replace("*", "");

Comment: simply the select listview value which are always filled

Comment: It's literally just a bog standard viewholder pattern, with holder.textView.setText(UserModel.geTitle());

Comment: I see. I was asking only because the error seems literally strange to me. It comes from the sdk itself, or at least seems so, are you sure the stacktrace referes to the snippet? Are you sure that you are always providing a not null parameter? You can also check the addData code on grepcode and see if you can find something about